# Passing array to a function in Bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: bash

I am trying to pass a string array to a function in Bash which results in "syntax error near unexpected token `('"

```
 #!/usr/bin/env bash                                                                

 function __test() {                                                                
   my_command -c ("a" "b" "c" "d")                                                                                           
 }
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: In brief, you are assuming `(a b c d)` is an array value, when no such value exists. `bash` only has array *variables*, which provide syntax for addressing individual string values using the same variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a syntax violation, just do,

```
function __test() {                                                                
   my_command -c "a" "b" "c" "d"                                                                                          
}
```

to pass the four strings to `my_command`. The `()` is a syntax in `bash` for execution under a sub-shell which is probably not applicable here.

(or) using an array

```
function __test() { 
   local myArray=("a" "b" "c" "d" )                                                               
   my_command -c "${myArray[@]}"                                                                                         
}
```

Your idea of using the array is right, but pass the array as a whole as `${myArray[@]}` to the command.

You asked for a `getopts` to handle this, and here is how you handle it. There are two ways to do this,

To pass the arguments as a single quoted string "a b c d"

```
usage() { echo "Usage: $0 [-c args]" 1>&2; exit 1; }

[ $# -eq 0 ] && usage

while getopts ":c:" arg; do
  case $arg in
    c)
      IFS=' ' 
      argsC=($OPTARG)
      ;;

    *) 
      usage; exit 0
      ;;
  esac
done

printf "%s\n" "Number of arguments: ${#argsC[@]}"
```

and running now,

```
./script.sh -c "a b c d"
Number of arguments: 4
a
b
c
d
```

and for sending as multiple strings, add the `OPTARG` value to the array, changing the `getopts` part alone,

```
while getopts ":c:" arg; do
  case $arg in
    c)
      argsC+=($OPTARG)
      ;;

    *) 
      usage; exit 0
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Now running the script,

```
./script.sh -c "a" -c "b" -c "c" -c "d"
Number of arguments: 4
a
b
c
d
du
```

Use this  [[shell check]](https://www.shellcheck.net)  site for syntactically verifying your scripts.

Comment: Ah, right. How can I get that array as an argument of -c option when parsing with getopts ? It only gives me "a" as the argument

Comment: Actually never mind, think I know how. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have Bash pass an array by reference, or have it copied as a single entity.

There are two approaches to achieving the desired result.

The first one is copying the data

```
 function __test()
 {
   declare -a array=("a" "b" "c" "d")
   my_command -c "${array[@]}"
 }

my_command()
{
  # Handle options
  [[ "$1" != -c ]] || shift
  # Get your data back in array form by collecting
  # positional parameters in an array
  declare -a array=("$@")
  # Display element at position 2
  echo "${array[2]}"
  # Display all elements
  echo "${array[@]}"
}
```

If `mycommand` is an external program in another language, then you would receive the data as positional parameters.

The second approach is indirection, and will only work if the data is used inside the same Bash script  so that the variable can be access in the same scope.

```
 function __test()
 {
   declare -a array=("a" "b" "c" "d")
   my_command -c array
 }

my_command()
{
  # Handle options
  [[ "$1" != -c ]] || shift
  varname="$1"
  # Access element at position 2
  x="$varname[2]"
  echo "${!x}"
  # Access all elements
  x="$varname[@]"
  echo "${!x}"
}
```

You need to make sure the variable name used does not contain any unwanted data, or else there could be risks or code injection, so unless the variable name is fully under the control of your program (no chance of user input being included in the variable name), you have to find a way to sanitize it.

Recent variables of bash have a `-n` option in variable declaration statements (such as `local`) which you may also want to take a look at, but I would think this is not deployed widely enough to be used except for known configurations.

Please note that I would normally declare all variables `local` in functions unless I have a specific reason for not doing so, this has been omitted in the code above for clarity purposes.

Comment: Why do you want to add stuff that is not needed in the scope of current question? The question's scope ended at fixing the syntax issue either passing the individual words or as an array both of which I attempted to answer. Appreciate your efforts, but this creates just too much redundancy for such a trivial answer.

Comment: @Inian I very much appreciate and find this answer very useful and educational. Clearly my example of using array begs for this answer

Comment: Well, it depends how you interpret the OP question, i.e. whether you concentrate on the "syntax error" or "passing an array".  I tried to provide ways for the OP to get the data back in array form on the other side of the call, which I (maybe incorrectly) assumed he was trying to do.

Comment: @Bren: If you hadn't seen it already. I already updated the mine with arrays,

Comment: @Fred: Same as above, my answer already has that way of using the arrays

Comment: I would appreciate if someone more expert than I am would comment on the potential for code injection in this code.  I assumed there is a risk, but I am not entirely sure if it is the case with ${!x} expansion (cannot figure how how it could happen), so I would not want to leave false impressions here.

Comment: Code injection (for the redirection version) is easy: `my_command -c 'a[$(ls>&2)]'`.

Comment: Ok, now I remember seeing the array index evaluation risk mentioned.  So I will leave the comments in my post.  Thanks!

Comment: @Bren: You wanted a `getopts` to handle to arguments?? Refer my update.